# Send values from one form to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I want to pass values between two Forms (c#). How can I do it?

I have two forms: Form1 and Form2.

Form1 contains one button. When I click on that button, Form2 should open and Form1 should be in inactive mode (i.e not selectable).

Form2 contains one text box and one submit button. When I type any message in Form2's text box and click the submit button, the Form2 should close and Form1 should highlight with the submitted value.

How can i do it? Can somebody help me to do this with a simple example.

Comment: Did you got any example for this ?

Answer (score 67):

There are several solutions to this but this is the pattern I tend to use.

```
// Form 1
// inside the button click event
using(Form2 form2 = new Form2()) 
{
    if(form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        someControlOnForm1.Text = form2.TheValue;
    }
}
```

And...

```
// Inside Form2
// Create a public property to serve the value
public string TheValue 
{
    get { return someTextBoxOnForm2.Text; }
}
```

Comment: I thought this was bad code conduct. This is great then. I will also use this pattern

Comment: Well, I don't think it's bad "conduct", however there are security implications to consider before using this pattern. (But, great simple example +1)

Comment: Also don't forget that you also will need to have on form2 instead of form2.Close(); use "DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;" or it will not detect the form was opened.

Comment: What security implications are there?

Comment: @seedee - I expect the implication is that, because the property is public in this scope, its accessibility extends beyond the classes through which it's being accessed. In this case, it's providing direct access to a user input's text field property to potentially malicious code executing outside these classes. Imagine if that's the input field for passwords...

Answer (score 45):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        frm2.Show();    
}
```

---

```
 public Form2(string qs)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = qs;

    }
```

Comment: i have tested this code, if we don't call the default constructor of Form2,  `public Form2(string qs):this(){}` the form will not be shown well.

Comment: This is the option I used and it worked just fine for me!

Comment: This one didn't work for me on winforms. That looks more like WPF solution!

Answer (score 18):

Define a property

```
public static class ControlID {  
    public static string TextData { get; set; }
}
```

In the **`Form1`**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    ControlID.TextData = txtTextData.Text;   
}
```

Getting the data in **`Form1`** and **`Form2`**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string text=  ControlID.TextData;   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

After a series of struggle for passing the data from one form to another i finally found a stable answer. It works like charm.

All you need to do is declare a variable as `public static datatype 'variableName'` in one form and assign the value to this variable which you want to pass to another form and call this variable in another form using directly the form name (**Don't create object of this form as static variables can be accessed directly**) and access this variable value.

Example of such is,

**Form1**

```
public static int quantity;
quantity=TextBox1.text; \\Value which you want to pass
```

**Form2**

```
TextBox2.Text=Form1.quantity;\\ Data will be placed in TextBox2
```

Comment: The issue of this approach is if you have multiple of Form1 opened, they override the "quantity" value. And your Form2 gets the value of latest opened Form1.

Answer (score 4):

Declare a public string in `form1`

```
public string getdata;
```

In button of `form1`

```
form2 frm= new form2();
this.hide();
form2.show();
```

To send data to `form1` you can try any event and code following in that event

```
form1 frm= new form1();
form1.getdata="some string to be sent to form1";
```

Now after closing of `form2` and opening of `form1`, you can use returned data in `getdata` string.

Comment: I and doing the same as suggested by you in my forms but the issue I am getting is that return value doesn't appear in text field as long as I hit push button again.

Answer (score 3):

I've worked on various winform projects and as the applications gets more complex (more dialogs and interactions between them) then i've started to use some eventing system to help me out, because management of opening and closing windows manually will be hard to maintain and develope further.

I've used [CAB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx) for my applications, it has an [eventing system](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/09/23/events-in-the-cab-introduction-to-cabscsf-part-12/) but it might be an overkill in your case :) You could [write your own events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx) for simpler applications

Comment: +1 for events, they scale nicely.  But where do you actually store the values?  A static class is simple enough, but that's close to using a global variable, it feels... icky.  Does each form have its own local variable for settings which relate to it?

Answer (score 3):

Form1 Code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            MessageBox.Show("Form1 Message :"+Form2.t.Text); //can put label also in form 1 to show the value got from form2
}
```

Form2 Code :

```
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            t = textBox1;                        //Initialize with static textbox
        }
        public static TextBox t=new TextBox();   //make static to get the same value as inserted
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Close();

        }
```

It Works!

Answer (score 2):

declare string in form1
public string TextBoxString;

in form1 click event add

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 newform = new Form1();
        newform = this;
        this.Hide();
        MySecform = new Form2(ref newform);
        MySecform.Show();
    }
```

in form2 constructer

```
public Form2(ref Form1 form1handel)
    {
        firstformRef = form1handel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

in form2 crate variable Form1 firstformRef;

```
private void Submitt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstformRef.TextBoxString = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
        firstformRef.Show();

    }
```

Comment: Why create a new `Form1`?  Why not pass `this` to the `Form2` constructor?

Answer (score 2):

In this code, you pass a text to Form2. Form2 shows that text in textBox1.
User types new text into textBox1 and presses the submit button.
Form1 grabs that text and shows it in a textbox on Form1.

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    private string oldText;

    public Form2(string newText):this()
    {
        oldText = newText;
        btnSubmit.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = oldText;
    }

    public string getText()
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is Form1 code:

```
public class Form1:Form
{
    using (Form2 dialogForm = new Form2("old text to show in Form2"))
    {
        DialogResult dr = dialogForm.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tbSubmittedText = dialogForm.getText();
        }
        dialogForm.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so `Form1` has a textbox, first of all you have to set this `Form1` textbox to public in textbox property.

**Code Form1:**

```
Public button1_click()
{
    Form2 secondForm = new Form2(this);
    secondForm.Show();
}
```

Pass `Form1` as `this` in the constructor.

**Code Form2:**

```
Private Form1 _firstForm;

Public Form2(Form1 firstForm)
{
    _firstForm = firstForm:
}

Public button_click()
{
    _firstForm.textBox.text=label1.text;
    This.Close();
}
```

Comment: Came to this Post because of a diff. Question i answered. This is prefered and in a modern Program, passing the mainform to the childrenforms will often be helpful. This should be the prefered answer imo

Answer (score 1):

you can pass as parameter the textbox of the Form1, like this:

On Form 1 buttom handler:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form2 newWindow = new Form2(textBoxForReturnValue);
newWindow.Show(); 
}
```

On the Form 2

```
public static TextBox textBox2; // class atribute

public Form2(TextBox textBoxForReturnValue)
{
    textBox2= textBoxForReturnValue;
}

private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim();
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are the best ways to pass data between forms or Gui Objects you can do this.
In the form1 click button you should have:

```
Form1.Enable = false;
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.ShowDialog();
```

In form 2, when the user clicks the button it should have a code like this or similar:

```
this.Close();
Form1 form = new Form1(textBox1.Text)
form.Show();
```

Once inside the form load of form 1 you can add code to do anything as you get the values from constructor.

Comment: Thanks.  This makes the most sense to me.  I tried everything else on this page and this was the only one that worked!

Answer (score 0):

**How to pass the values from form to another form**

1.) Goto Form2 then Double click it. At the code type this.

```
public Form2(string v)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  textBox1.Text = v;
}
```

2.) Goto Form1 then Double click it. At the code type this.
//At your command button in Form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 F2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
   F2.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.
suppose you have 2 window form Form1 and Form2 and you want to send record of textbox1 from Form1 to Form2 and display this record in label1 of Form2;
then in Form2 create a label which name is label1 and go to the property of label1 and set 'Modifiers'=public and in Form one create a textBox with id textBox1 and a button of name submit then write the following code on button click event

```
button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 obj=new Form2();
  obj.label1.text=textBox1.text.ToString();
  obj.show();
}
```

thats it...
for this way you can bind dataset record to another form's datagridview......

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a different approach if you like.

1. Using System.Action  (Here you simply pass the main forms function as the parameter to the child form like a callback function)
2. OpenForms Method ( You directly call one of your open forms)

**Using System.Action**

You can think of it as a callback function passed to the child form.

```
// -------- IN THE MAIN FORM --------

// CALLING THE CHILD FORM IN YOUR CODE LOOKS LIKE THIS
Options frmOptions = new Options(UpdateSettings);
frmOptions.Show();

// YOUR FUNCTION IN THE MAIN FORM TO BE EXECUTED
public void UpdateSettings(string data)
{
   // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
}

// -------- IN THE CHILD FORM --------

Action<string> UpdateSettings = null;

// IN THE CHILD FORMS CONSTRUCTOR
public Options(Action<string> UpdateSettings)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.UpdateSettings = UpdateSettings;
}

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // CALLING THE CALLBACK FUNCTION
    if (UpdateSettings != null)
        UpdateSettings("some data");
}
```

**OpenForms Method**

This method is easy (**2 lines**). But only works with forms that are open.
All you need to do is add these two lines where ever you want to pass some data.

```
Main frmMain = (Main)Application.OpenForms["Main"];
frmMain.UpdateSettings("Some data");
```

I provided my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48920278/3436775)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this;

Form1 button1 click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    this.Hide();
    frm2.Show();
}
```

And add this to Form2

```
public string info = "";
```

Form2 button1 click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    info = textBox1.Text;
    this.Hide();
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        Gogo();
    }));
}

public void Gogo()
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.Show();
    frm.Text = info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change Modifiers Property of a control in a Form to Public, another Forms can access to that control.
f.e. :

```
    Form2 frm;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(frm.txtUserName.Text); 
        //txtUserName is a TextBox with Modifiers=Public        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// In form 1
public static string Username = Me;

// In form 2's load block
string _UserName = Form1.Username;
```

Answer (score 0):

the tag Properties receive object value
( C# send value to another form )

```
private void btn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form frm = new formToSend();
    frm.tag = obj;
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Receive value that sent from previous form ( frm )
Ex: sent data is string ( we need to type casting first, because tag value is an object )

```
public Receive_Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show((string)this.Tag);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using a public Event

I would do it like this.

```
public class Form2
{
   public event Action<string> SomethingCompleted;

   private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SomethingCompleted?.Invoke(txtData.Text);
       this.Close();
   }
}
```

and call it from Form1 like this.

```
private void btnOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var frm = new Form2())
    {
        frm.SomethingCompleted += text => {
            this.txtData.Text = text;
        };

        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Then, Form1 could get a text from Form2 when Form2 is closed

Thank you.