# how do you send data from one form to another in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Basically I have created a program which records customer details, when they enter the details, the information needs to appear into the other form when a button is pressed, I am new to c# so detailed help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using web forms or windows forms?

Comment: Are you working in ASP.Net or WPF or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form-in-c-sharp-winforms-application

Comment: I'm using windows form and i think it's ASP.net

Comment: i think ..?? web or desktop ??

Comment: @user2519350: Windows Form on ASP.NET? What are you talking about?

Comment: A good article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms

Comment: I'm using windows forms and im working in ASP.Net i think

Comment: like i said, i'm new to all this stuff i don't even know what ASP.net or WPF is...

Comment: @user2519350 are you sure this is C#? Maybe Ruby?

Comment: I'm positive this is c#...this is part of my assignment, i'm using visual studio as the IDE if that helps..

Comment: Does your web browser open when you try to run it?

Comment: It sounds like you are using either Windows forms or WPF. You don't appear to be using ASP.NET.

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit please.  Is the other form on a different page?  What have you tried already?  What problems have you run into?  The more information you give us, the better we can help you.  Please take a look at ["how do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when you get time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article I wrote about passing values around between Windows Forms (it includes variations depending on how the forms are related to one another) a while ago. Here it is: http://colinmackay.co.uk/2005/04/22/passing-values-between-forms-in-net/

If you are using WPF (and I can't quite tell if you are or not, but I suspect a beginners assignment would be more tending towards WinForms anyway) then the article may not be as much use as WPF does things a little differently.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows form then you will have to set up some properties which will get and set values on the second form and then pass the values from the 1st form. This is just one of the techniques of passing values.

```
//Code on your form 2
private string strClass;
private int iRollNo;
..
  public string StrClass
    {
      get { return this.strClass; }
      set { this.strClass= value; }
     }

    public int IRollNo
    {
      get { return this.iRollNo; }
      set { this.iRollNo= value; }
    }

 //code on form1
  Form2 objFrom2 = new Form2();
  objFrom2.strClass= "10th";
  objFrom2.iRollNo= 1;
  objFrom2.ShowDialog(); //show the form.
```