# Assigning textbox value to a field in a separate form

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, event-handling

I am sure this is an easy question to answer, but I am having difficulty implementing it how I need.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and C#

I have two forms, one that loads when the app starts up which contains user-selectable settings such as user id, how many puzzle pieces that would like on screen... and a confirm button.

The second form is like a puzzle grid, which is generated when the user clicks the confirm button on the first form.

When the person has correctly solved the puzzle, a message box pops up with the time it took to solve.

What I want to be able to do is add the user id field into the messagebox string.

I have seen many examples of using event args and getting and setting fields but most are assuming one form is generated from a previous form, where I just want to 'grab' the information from one form and store it on the second form for use in a string.

Links to tutorials would also be appreciated if that is easier.

---

I found out what I was doing wrong, with the help of everyone's answers.

I had the variables declared on the first form, but they were declared in the textbox_leave and updownBox_leave methods when they should have been declared at the very top of the class.

Then I just called Form1.IdString and Form1.puzzleNumberString from my Form2 and what-do-you-know everything went as I thought it should.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form-in-c-sharp-winforms-application

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer I had read that question before posting, it was close to what I was asking, but their program path was quite different to the approach I was taking. Thank you for taking time to view my question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple.All you need to do is pass your id variable to second form constructor.For example in your Confirm Button click:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(myVariable);
f2.Show();
```

And you should add a constructor to the `Form2:`

```
public string ID { get; set; }

public Form2(string id)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ID = id;
}
```

Then you can use `ID` variable in your second form.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It didn't quite work for me. I will probably just restart the project with a different arrangement of Forms so that some tutorials will be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

In your puzzle form create a global Form variable, then give the constructor a `Form f` parameter and set your global `form` variable as the passed parameter:

```
public Form form = null;
public PuzzleForm(Form f) //puzzle form constructor
{
    form = f;
}
```

then go into your first form and where you create an instance of the puzzle form change it so that it passes an instance of this.

```
PuzzleForm pf = new PuzzleForm(this);
```

Now from inside your Puzzle form you can access your Form1 variables like so `MessageBox.Show("UserID: "+form.userID.Text);`