# Hiding buttons in one web form through another web from in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem and it is like that I have two forms in asp.net, In one form I have Button1 one and in another form I have two buttons, Button1 and Buton2 now when I click Button1 in first web form the buttons of other web form should hide, how this can be done in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Solution1 : You can use Sessions as below on `Button_Click` Event

```
Session["DisableButtons"] = "True"
```

In 2nd page of Load Event you can check as below

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 if (Session["DisableButtons"] = "True")
 {
 btn1.Visible = False;
 btn2.Visible = False;
 }
}
```

Solution 2 : You can send a variable's value in the URL when you are doing `Response.Redirect` and you can fetch from URL using `Request.QueryString`.

Comment: We can use Cross Page posting also if we are going to do this with the help of Request.QuertString

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ButtonID1").click(function(){
    $("#ButtonID2").hide() //or .toggle(); if you want to hide/show
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Send values from one form to another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form-in-c-sharp-winforms-application)

you can use the logic from here for hiding the contents of webfroms using another either you can use Session  .

I don't have enough Reputation else it will be  posted in comment 
 .

Thank you

Udit Bhardwaj