# fetch data datagridview in second form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two `forms`. In form1 I have two `comboboxes` which takes two parameters from a `store procedure` and a `button` to fire the results. The results should be displayed  in `form2` which has a `datagridview` when the button is clicked.

My code in form1 (btn event). Don't really know if it is correct

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string C = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["D"].ConnectionString;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(C))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())

        {
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            cmd.CommandText = ("[dbo].[spInfo]");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Periode2", cbPeriode2.SelectedValue.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Periode1", cbPeriode1.SelectedValue.ToString());
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           if(myReader.HasRows)
            {
                DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                datatable.Load(myReader);
                //datagridview1.DataSource = datatable;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    new Form2().ShowDialog();
}
```

Form2 (formload event)
I don't know how to fetch the records here

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
}
```

Comment: What's the problem/question?

Comment: How to get the records in form2 datagridview if the button is clicked in form1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send values from one form to another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the data from form1 to form2
**From Form1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string C = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["D"].ConnectionString;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(C))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())

            {
                SqlDataReader myReader;
                cmd.CommandText = ("[dbo].[spInfo]");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Periode2", cbPeriode2.SelectedValue.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Periode1", cbPeriode1.SelectedValue.ToString());
                con.Open();
                myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable datatable = new DataTable();    
               if(myReader.HasRows)
                {

                    datatable.Load(myReader);
                    //datagridview1.DataSource = datatable;
                }
                con.Close();
                ShowForm2(datatable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
public void ShowForm2(DataTable yourData)
{
    DataTable Data = yourData;
    Form2 frm = new Form2(Data);
    frm.Show();
}
```

**On Form2**

```
public class Form2
{
     public Form2()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Default Consturctor
     }
     private DataTable LocalData;
     public Form2(DataTable Data)
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        LocalData = Data;
     }
     public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
              //Consume LocalData Here
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Is myData in form1 = my database connection? And what's the meaning of LocalData? Thnx

Comment: Check the edited code, replace your code with the above code for form1, and LocalData is a variable in Form2

Comment: Thnx for the and the logic