# Send data from a listbox to a label on another form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a menu where I can add items to a list box using an add button.

I then have a button to send the order so to speak.

The button to send the order I need it to be able to send what is in the list box to a label (or even list box?) on another form.

So far I am only able to write my own text in a text box and then send it to a label on another form, I can't work out how to use what is in the list box to send to that label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send values from one form to another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form). Such questions should be nominated as **the most often asked questions without using search**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

- In your first form with the listbox

  ```
  Form2 f = new Form2(listBox1);
  f.Show();
  ```
- In second form with label

  ```
  public Form2(ListBox listy)
  {
      InitializeComponent();

       foreach (var item in listy.Items)
       {
          label1.Text += item.ToString();
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks this worked a treat, however when I add to the label it is coming up like 'ItemItemItemItem' where as I need them on seperate lines as it is an order confirmation I am trying to do.