# Is this correct? Calling ListView from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm wondering if I'm doing this correctly, calling a `listview1` from another form. So I can use a query involving `listView1` of the `Transactions` form.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///transactions goback = new transactions();
    //goback.button6.Enabled = true;
    //this.Hide();
    transactions reba = new transactions();
    reba.listView1 = new ListView();
}
```

Comment: Where are you *"calling"* a listview? In this code snippet you are creating a new instance of a `ListView`

Comment: oohhhhhh  i see  how should i approach tho?

Comment: To improve the Quality of the Question as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, please give greater evidence of what research you have done and how things are not working versus how you wanted to work (inluding any error message, unexpected results, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access the `listview1` from another form because it is a private field. But you can access it if you create a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) for it:

Fist go to the `Designer` file of the `transactions` form (`transactions.Designer.cs`) and add the following property to it:

```
public ListView ListView1
{
    get { return listView1; }
    set { listView1 = value; }
}
```

Then you can access to it from another form:

```
transactions reba = new transactions();
reba.ListView1...
```

Comment: good example indeed. May be you should add that OP should not create a new instance of the transaction form but use the one which has a non-empty `ListView`

Comment: ohh so creating a new instance erases the listview items? Sorry im really new to this but im getting the hang of it XD

Comment: @ReberLot think of an object/instance as a box. Everything inside the box is gone if you simply throw that box out and place a new box in its place (thats what your doing with = new transactions() and new ListView().

Comment: OHHH i see! , how do i call the ones with contents ? inside it ?  what approach should i use

Comment: @ReberLot you need to pass the instance of the transaction form to the second one. Have a look at [Send values from one form to another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form)

Comment: @ReberLot This answer is about *Calling ListView from another form* as you want but to access the old `ListView` with contents you need to pass it to the new form as Mong Zhu said.

Comment: I see! now its starting to clear up! THANKS very much! you three! :D