# How to control method with other class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to sent data from one class to other using method.

e.x. 
**This is form1**

```
namespace sof
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.Show();
    }

    public void data(string name,bool re)
    {
        label1.Text = name;
        if (re == true)
            label1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        else
            label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

**This is Form2**

```
    namespace sof
    {
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form1 f1 = new Form1(); 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1.data("Alex",true);
    }
}
    }
```

> Now I want from Form2 sent this data(**f1.data("Alex",true);**) back to Form1 and set label1 tex.

***Thanks in advance for your help***

Comment: This answers your question: [Send values from one form to another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form)  If not, there are [thousands more here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+data+to+another+form+c%23+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS460US460&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-vc62surmAhVXHc0KHelCD30QrQIoBDAAegQIBBAN&biw=1179&bih=774)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a reason you instantiate a new `Form1` inside your `Form2`, but i would try obtaining a reference to caller `Form1` instance and setting a propery on it directly:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2; // it's a bit of a catch - you will have to instantiate your f2 in a method to access `this`
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 f1
    public Form2(Form1 f1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.f1 = f1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1.data("Alex", true);
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason your `data()` is not public, passing a delegate could work:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2; // it's a bit of a catch - you will have to instantiate your f2 in a method to access non-static class members
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2 = new Form2((name, re) => data(name, re)); // so you pass your delegate here
        f2 = new Form2(data); // this will also work given your member signature match
        f2.Show();
    }

    public void data(string name, bool re)
    {

    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Action<string, bool> _setData;

    public Form2(Action<string, bool> setData)
    {       
        _setData = setData;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _setData("Alex", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new instance of Form1 inside Form2, you need to pass a reference to Form1 into the constructor of Form2.  Then use this reference to call the `Form1.data()` method in your button click event handler.

So your code would look like this.

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.Show();
    }

    public void data(string name,bool re)
    {
        label1.Text = name;
        if (re == true)
            label1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        else
            label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 f1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        f1 = form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1.data("Alex",true);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Just to point out, I suspect the ‘new Form2(this)’ will not compile.