# Form 2 With ListBox Value Pass In Form4 Label "Help Me"

Tags: c#

[image]

[image]

this listbox value pass in Form 4 If I Will Select
i Will Try This Command

```
  Form4 f4 = new Form4();
  F4.label.Text = lisbox1.Selectitem.Tostring();
```

I Will Select Control SelectIndexChanger

this Is label Form4 select listbox value Show here

Comment: The (imho) easiest and cleanest way to share this information is by having the forms share a model. There are many examples about MVC in Winforms, just hack it into your search engine of choice.

Comment: For send value between forms, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/60292238/2133965

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters through the constructor

Form 4

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4(string value)
        {
            F4.label.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

In Form 1

```
 Form4 form = new Form4(lisbox1.Selectitem.Tostring());
 form.ShowDialog();
```

Hope to help you

Comment: Error Give System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

label1 was null.

Comment: Try to add `InitializeComponent();before F4.label.Text = value;

Comment: In Which Form  public Playlist()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Main main = new Main();
            

        }

Comment: public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4(string value)
        {
            label1.Text = value;
        }
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }

Comment: Make A Video For Exapmle Stay On Same Page Value but Result give me on show Dilago

Comment: I think you need use parent form. May be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform?view=netcore-3.1 can help you

Comment: label show me in with showdialog (); or label show me without showdialog