# How to use get, set in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have two windows form, and I can transfer data between them by using (get, set), the code is in below:

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public TextBox tb1
    {
        get { return textBoxinForm1; }
        set { textBoxinForm1 = value; }
    }

    private void buttonSendtoForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
        form2.tb2.Text = textBoxinForm1.Text;
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public TextBox tb2
    {
        get { return textBoxinForm2; }
        set { textBoxinForm2 = value; }
    }

    private void buttonSendtoForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
        form1.tb1.Text = textBoxinForm2.Text;
    }
}
```

When I try to do the same but with windows (WPF), I have error below "textBoxinForm2", "textBoxinForm1"and "value". So, how to fix that..

Comment: you need to ensure that there is `textBoxinForm2` field in `Form2`

Comment: I'm sure it in the form 2,  the code is run ok in windows form but it have error in WPF

Comment: *Which* error message do you get?

Comment: The main error in this line (Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]; as it is for windows form not for WPF, to explaine the two windows are open and Itried to send text from textbox of one form to another

Comment: Do you want to pass values between two windows in WPF? WPF and WinForm are not exactly the same in delivering value.

Comment: Yes, that what I need exactly, I need to pass values between two open forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding WPF code to get a reference to a `Window1` class would be this:

```
private void buttonSendtoForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window1 form1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window1>().FirstOrDefault();
    form1.tb1.Text = textBoxinForm2.Text;
}
```