# How do I transfer data from a textbox to a data grid view in another winform via a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

I have two forms, form1 and credentials. I want the data in my textbox (can be filled by user) to be transferred to the data grid view in form1.

Also, in form1, I want the data in my labels to be also transferred into the data grid view, which is also in form1. The labels I want to be transferred are: score, timer, level

I have tried and research for multiple solutions, yet none can really solve my problem. however, I tried to combine the solutions from websites and here is what i can do that kind of make sense to me. following are the codes for form1 and credentials.

form1 source code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Snake mySnake;
    Board mainBoard;
    Rewards apples;

    string mode;
    Timer clock;
    int duration; //How long the game has been running
    int speed = 500; //500ms
    int score;
    int highscore;
    int level;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //button2.Text = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x2197);

        //You don't have to worry about the auto-size
        this.AutoSize = true;       //The size of the Form will autoadjust.
        boardPanel.AutoSize = true; //The size of the panel grouping all the squares will auto-adjust

        //Set up the main board
        mainBoard = new Board(this);

        //Set up the game timer at the given speed
        clock = new Timer();
        clock.Interval = speed; //Set the clock to tick every 500ms
        clock.Tick += new EventHandler(refresh); //Call the refresh method at every tick to redraw the board and snake.

        duration = 0;
        score = 0;
        highscore = 0;
        level = 1;
        modeLBL.Text = mode;

        gotoNextLevel(level);

        scoresDGV.ColumnCount = 4;
        scoresDGV.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Name";
        scoresDGV.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Level";
        scoresDGV.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Score";
        scoresDGV.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Timer";
        scoresDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        scoresDGV.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        scoresDGV.MultiSelect = false;
        scoresDGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        scoresDGV.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    }

    private void refresh(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        //increment the duration by amount of time that has passed
        //this method is called every speed millisecond
        duration += speed;
        timerLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(duration / 1000); //Show time passed

        //Check if snke is biting itself. If so, call GameOver.
        if (mySnake.checkEatItself() == true)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (apples.checkIFSnakeHeadEatApple( mySnake.getHeadPosition()) == true)
        {
            score += apples.eatAppleAtPostion(mySnake.getHeadPosition());

            scoreLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(score);


            if (apples.noMoreApples() == true)
            {
                clock.Stop();
                level++;
                levelLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(level);
                gotoNextLevel(level);
                MessageBox.Show("Press the start button to go to Level " + level, "Congrats");
            }
            else
            {
                //Length the snake and continue with the Game
                mySnake.extendBody();
            }
        }

        if (score > highscore)
        {
            highscoreLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(highscore);
        }
    }

    private void startBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clock.Start();
    }
    private void pauseBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clock.Stop();
    }
    private void restartBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //snapBTN
    {
        duration = 0;
        mySnake.draw();
    }
    private void backBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // hides the form from the user. in this case, the program hides the HowToPlay form
        this.Hide();
        MainMenu mM = new MainMenu();
        mM.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void GameOver()
    {
        clock.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Your time taken is " + duration/1000 + " seconds. Bye Bye", "Game Over");
        this.Close();

        addCurrentScoresToDatabase();
        //updateScoreBoard();
    }
    private void modeLBL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void addCurrentScoresToDatabase()
    {
        Credentials c = new Credentials();
        c.ShowDialog();
    }

}

credentials source code:
```

```
public partial class Credentials : Form
    {
        public static string SetValueForName = "";
        public Credentials()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void saveBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetValueForName = enternameTB.Text;

            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.Show();
        }
        private void cancelBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/834980/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-form-in-windows-form/

Answer (score 0):

Because part of your code is made in the designer (and not shown here in your post) it is difficult to understand how it works. I assume you have a simple dialog form which is shown in your form1
Credentials is shown modal. So if you have some properties in your credentials dialog, you may data transfer via the properties.

```
   private void addCurrentScoresToDatabase()
    {
        Credentials c = new Credentials();
    // initialize c here
        c.ShowDialog();
    // read data from c here
    }
```

If you want get data from the credential dialog while it is shown, you should use events.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer score, timer, level to datagridview and transfer Name from credentials to datagridview, you can refer to the following code:

Code in Form1：

```
int index;
public void AddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index = scoresDGV.Rows.Add();
        scoresDGV.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = label1.Text; 
        scoresDGV.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = label2.Text; 
        scoresDGV.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = label3.Text;
        Credentials c = new Credentials();
        c.FormClosed += c_FormClosed;
        c.Show();
    }
void c_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        scoresDGV.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = Credentials.SetValueForName;
    }
```

Code in Credentials：

```
public partial class Credentials : Form
{
    public static string SetValueForName = "";
    public Credentials()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void saveBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetValueForName = enternameTB.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is the test result：
[image]